# Using flex with a ribbon card component with offset cards. How to align items which are variable in length

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Apologies in advance if this is a badly worded question. I am trying to build a component which looks like this from the design: [image]

We have a tagline and title then the option to have 1 to 4 cards in the ribbon. These are ordered using `flex-direction: row-reverse` (so they stack from the right hand side first).

We pass a data attribute via the backend, so we can target a ribbon with 1 - 4 cards.

So far I have built this using offsets of padding, margins and height, this works well when we have copy as we expect, but if the title is very short (or long) everything gets messed up. I am not even sure (given the way the component has been built) if this is even possible. Mobile is fine, and 1 or 2 cards is OK, but 3 or 4 gets tricky. We want to align the first two at the top (from the right hand side) then the third is taller and should align at the bottom with the 4th card (so 3 and 4 have an offset). Maybe it is better to think of the title and tagline as being offset?

I have made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/cqsmj34e/) using the 4 card layout.

Here is the sample HTML:

```
<section class="ribbon-icon grid grid-container content-wrapper" data-columns="4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ribbon-icon__title col col--md-6">
            <p class="ribbon-icon__tagline">Solutions</p>
            <p class="h1">Improve the benefits that health care can provide Improve the benefits that health care can provide..</p>
            <p class="ribbon-icon__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus porta rhoncus pharetra amet, consequat ullamcorper vitae sed. Dolor sem tellus nec risus magna.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ribbon-icon__items row col">
                <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3" href="/en-gb">
                    <div>
                        <img src="/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Clinical studies</h3>
                        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3" href="/en-gb">
                    <div>
                        <img src="/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Clinical studies</h3>
                        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3" href="/en-gb">
                    <div>
                        <img src="/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Patient information material</h3>
                        <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3" href="/en-gb">
                    <div>
                        <img src="/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Product information</h3>
                        <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

We are using scss but I have made a dump of the core css this relates to (it's in the fiddle of course) but here is the block:

```
.ribbon-icon {
    margin-bottom: -4.5rem
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .ribbon-icon {
        margin-bottom: -2.5rem
    }
}

.ribbon-icon__title {
    margin: 0!important;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .ribbon-icon__title {
        margin: 0 0 6rem!important
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .ribbon-icon__title .h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem!important
    }
}

.ribbon-icon__description {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.ribbon-icon__item-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .ribbon-icon__item-title {
        font-size: 1.875rem;
        line-height: 2.25rem
    }
}

.ribbon-icon__items {
    flex-direction: row-reverse!important;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .ribbon-icon__items {
        position: relative;
        top: -7rem
    }
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item {
    position: relative;
    color: initial;
    margin: 1.25rem 0 2.25rem;
    text-decoration: none
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item:before {
    content: "";
    border-width: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(#b5007c, #007da3) 0 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 1.2rem)
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item:hover {
    color: initial
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item p {
    margin: 0
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item img,
.ribbon-icon__items--item svg {
    max-width: 3.25rem
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .ribbon-icon__items--item img,
    .ribbon-icon__items--item svg {
        max-width: 5rem
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .ribbon-icon__items--item {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0
    }
}

.ribbon-icon[data-columns="1"] .ribbon-icon__title {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .ribbon-icon[data-columns="3"] .ribbon-icon__items--item:nth-child(2),
    .ribbon-icon[data-columns="4"] .ribbon-icon__items--item:nth-child(2) {
        min-height: 30rem
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .ribbon-icon[data-columns="3"] .ribbon-icon__items--item:nth-child(3),
    .ribbon-icon[data-columns="3"] .ribbon-icon__items--item:nth-child(4),
    .ribbon-icon[data-columns="4"] .ribbon-icon__items--item:nth-child(3),
    .ribbon-icon[data-columns="4"] .ribbon-icon__items--item:nth-child(4) {
        top: 7rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is dependent on what are the design limits. There are cases in which you will not have enough space for four cards and the titles; in this case, would you prefer the title and tag line to be above the cards? or to form the cards in a "square shape", i.e. 2X2

Comment: We could have some flexibility in this from the BE. So if the component has 1 - 2 cards we render it a particular way, but for 3 -4 cards we could render it with the title inside the wrapper that contains the cards so they align.

Comment: got you, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:left` for the title and `float:right` for items:

```css
.row {
  border-top: 1px dotted gray;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ribbon-icon__title {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.ribbon-icon__tagline {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row .h1 {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row p {
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.row .ribbon-icon__description {
  font-size: 0.4rem;
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item {
  float: right;
  width: 24%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid pink;
  border-right: 1px solid pink;
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item:first-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ribbon-icon__items--item p {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  color: gray;
}

.ribbon-icon__item-title {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="ribbon-icon grid grid-container content-wrapper" data-columns="4" data-tracking="ribbon-icon">
<span>To see all the use cases scroll down till bottom.</span>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon-icon__title col col--md-6">
      <p class="ribbon-icon__tagline">Solutions</p>
      <p class="h1">Improve the benefits that health care can provide.</p>
      <p class="ribbon-icon__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus porta rhoncus pharetra amet, consequat ullamcorper vitae sed. Dolor sem tellus nec risus magna.</p>
    </div>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Product information4</h3>
        <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Patient information material3</h3>
        <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Clinical in-depth studies2</h3>
        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Webinars and e-learning</h3>
        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon-icon__title col col--md-6" style="width: 60%;">
      <p class="ribbon-icon__tagline">Solutions</p>
      <p class="h1">Improve the benefits that health care can provide.</p>
      <p class="ribbon-icon__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus porta rhoncus pharetra amet, consequat ullamcorper vitae sed. Dolor sem tellus nec risus magna.</p>
    </div>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Product information4</h3>
        <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Patient information material3</h3>
        <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Clinical in-depth studies2</h3>
        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Webinars and e-learning</h3>
        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon-icon__title col col--md-6" style="width: 20%;">
      <p class="ribbon-icon__tagline">Solutions</p>
      <p class="h1">Improve the benefits that health care can provide.</p>
      <p class="ribbon-icon__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus porta rhoncus pharetra amet, consequat ullamcorper vitae sed. Dolor sem tellus nec risus magna.</p>
    </div>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Product information4</h3>
        <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Patient information material3</h3>
        <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Clinical in-depth studies 2</h3>
        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies, and some more studies</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Webinars and e-learning</h3>
        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon-icon__title col col--md-6">
      <p class="ribbon-icon__tagline">Solutions</p>
      <p class="h1">Improve the benefits that health care can provide.</p>
      <p class="ribbon-icon__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus porta rhoncus pharetra amet, consequat ullamcorper vitae sed. Dolor sem tellus nec risus magna.</p>
    </div>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Product information4</h3>
        <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Patient information material3</h3>
        <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Clinical in-depth studies2</h3>
        <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon-icon__title col col--md-6">
      <p class="ribbon-icon__tagline">Solutions</p>
      <p class="h1">Improve the benefits that health care can provide.</p>
      <p class="ribbon-icon__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus porta rhoncus pharetra amet, consequat ullamcorper vitae sed. Dolor sem tellus nec risus magna.</p>
    </div>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Product information4</h3>
        <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Patient information material3</h3>
        <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon-icon__title col col--md-6">
      <p class="ribbon-icon__tagline">Solutions</p>
      <p class="h1">Improve the benefits that health care can provide.</p>
      <p class="ribbon-icon__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus porta rhoncus pharetra amet, consequat ullamcorper vitae sed. Dolor sem tellus nec risus magna.</p>
    </div>

    <a class="ribbon-icon__items--item col col--md-3">
      <div>
        <img src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF" />
        <h3 class="ribbon-icon__item-title">Product information4</h3>
        <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

To avoid complications I've not used all of your CSS rules. This is just a bare minimum code to demonstrate the layout. You can polish it further.

Comment: Thank you. It is very close, I like the idea of floats (old school) but as the content height is variable the container must use flex in order to align items to the top and bottom.

Comment: could you elaborate more? an image or an example on jsfiddle using my code demonstrating your use cases would be nice.

Comment: I forked your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/6gmLdwsp/ and added more text to a couple of the cards, the two on the right are fine, but the two on the left should extend to the bottom of the deepest card (which is why I was trying to use flex). Also you are passing a hard coded height value which I think will cause issues with variable content height.

Comment: @lharby I wish we could expand elements to the `line-height` without using flex or gird. This feels a lot like masonry layout, which is  still in specs for grid. [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71792633/15273968). I think you need to involve JavaScript. JS will also ensure this will behave the same in all browsers and devices.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will help.

I use eventlistener on button element because StackOverFlows snippet window calculates Title[h2] width not for a full screen but you can use
**window.addEventListener('load', () => {} )**

When you change title it will recalculate cards **margin-Top**

**Click resize button please.**

This is for 4

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('div');

const headerContainer = document.querySelector('.header-container');

let firstCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[0];
let secondCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[1];
let thirdCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[2];
let fourthCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[3];

const btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let childCount = mainContainer.childElementCount;
    
    if(childCount == 2){
        mainContainer.setAttribute('class','one-item-container')

        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card one-item-first-card ')
    }
    else if(childCount == 3){
        
        mainContainer.setAttribute('class','two-item-container')

        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card two-item-first-card ')

        secondCard.setAttribute('class','card two-item-second-card ')
    }

    else if(childCount > 3){

        mainContainer.setAttribute("class","more-item-container");
        headerContainer.setAttribute("class","more-header-container");
        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card more-first-card ');
        secondCard.setAttribute('class','card more-second-card');
        thirdCard.setAttribute('class','card third-card');

        const cardH2Element =  document.getElementById('cardTitle')

        const titleHeight = parseInt(cardH2Element.offsetHeight);

        firstCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 40}px`
        secondCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 40}px`
        thirdCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 100}px`

        if(childCount == 5){
            fourthCard.setAttribute('class','card fourth-card');
            fourthCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 100}px`
        }
    }
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2{
  font-weight:100;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

img{
  height: 60px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.one-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.two-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.more-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.header-container{
  padding: 2rem 6rem 0 0;
}

.header-container > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.more-header-container{
  padding: 2rem 6rem 0 0;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.more-header-container > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card{
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 1.5px 0  var(--c, #e0b9da);
  mask: linear-gradient(var(--p, 0deg), #0000 45%, #000 55%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card::after {
  --c: #b6dae7;
  --p: 180deg;
}


.card img{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card h3{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.card p{
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.one-item-first-card{
  grid-column: 2;
}

.two-item-first-card{
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.two-item-second-card{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.more-first-card{
  margin-bottom: calc(45%) ;
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.more-second-card{
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.third-card{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.fourth-card{
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}


button {
  position: absolute;
  top:5rem;
  right:5rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="header-container">
        <p>Solutions</p>
        <h2 id="cardTitle">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, tenetur.
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF"
            alt="Product Information"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Product Information</h3>
          <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D"
            alt="Patient Information"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Patient information material</h3>
          <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102"
            alt="Clinical Studies second"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Clinical Studies</h3>
          <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102"
            alt="Webinars and eLearning"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Webinars and eLearning</h3>
          <p>
            Get insights on pathophysiology, treatment and safety from experts
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button>Resize</button>
```

This is for 3

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('div');

const headerContainer = document.querySelector('.header-container');

let firstCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[0];
let secondCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[1];
let thirdCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[2];
let fourthCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[3];

const btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let childCount = mainContainer.childElementCount;
    
    if(childCount == 2){
        mainContainer.setAttribute('class','one-item-container')

        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card one-item-first-card ')
    }
    else if(childCount == 3){
        
        mainContainer.setAttribute('class','two-item-container')

        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card two-item-first-card ')

        secondCard.setAttribute('class','card two-item-second-card ')
    }

    else if(childCount > 3){

        mainContainer.setAttribute("class","more-item-container");
        headerContainer.setAttribute("class","more-header-container");
        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card more-first-card ');
        secondCard.setAttribute('class','card more-second-card');
        thirdCard.setAttribute('class','card third-card');

        const cardH2Element =  document.getElementById('cardTitle')

        const titleHeight = parseInt(cardH2Element.offsetHeight);

        firstCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 40}px`
        secondCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 40}px`
        thirdCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 100}px`

        if(childCount == 5){
            fourthCard.setAttribute('class','card fourth-card');
            fourthCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 100}px`
        }
    }
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2{
  font-weight:100;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

img{
  height: 60px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.one-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.two-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.more-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.header-container{
  padding: 2rem 6rem 0 0;
}

.header-container > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.more-header-container{
  padding: 2rem 6rem 0 0;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.more-header-container > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card{
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 1.5px 0  var(--c, #e0b9da);
  mask: linear-gradient(var(--p, 0deg), #0000 45%, #000 55%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card::after {
  --c: #b6dae7;
  --p: 180deg;
}


.card img{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card h3{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.card p{
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.one-item-first-card{
  grid-column: 2;
}

.two-item-first-card{
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.two-item-second-card{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.more-first-card{
  margin-bottom: calc(45%) ;
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.more-second-card{
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.third-card{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.fourth-card{
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}


button {
  position: absolute;
  top:5rem;
  right:5rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="header-container">
        <p>Solutions</p>
        <h2 id="cardTitle">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, tenetur.
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF"
            alt="Product Information"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Product Information</h3>
          <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D"
            alt="Patient Information"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Patient information material</h3>
          <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102"
            alt="Clinical Studies second"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Clinical Studies</h3>
          <p>Clinical trials, safety studies</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-microscope.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=277AE31475485774CD0094CBB39EC102"
            alt="Webinars and eLearning"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Webinars and eLearning</h3>
          <p>
            Get insights on pathophysiology, treatment and safety from experts
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->

    <button>Resize</button>
```

And This is for 2

```js
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('div');

const headerContainer = document.querySelector('.header-container');

let firstCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[0];
let secondCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[1];
let thirdCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[2];
let fourthCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card')[3];

const btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let childCount = mainContainer.childElementCount;

    if(childCount == 2){
        mainContainer.setAttribute('class','one-item-container')

        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card one-item-first-card ')
    }
    else if(childCount == 3){
        
        mainContainer.setAttribute('class','two-item-container')

        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card two-item-first-card ')

        secondCard.setAttribute('class','card two-item-second-card ')
    }

    else if(childCount > 3){
        
        mainContainer.setAttribute("class","more-item-container");
        headerContainer.setAttribute("class","more-header-container");
        firstCard.setAttribute('class','card more-first-card ');
        secondCard.setAttribute('class','card more-second-card');
        thirdCard.setAttribute('class','card third-card');

        const cardH2Element =  document.getElementById('cardTitle')

        const titleHeight = parseInt(cardH2Element.offsetHeight);

        firstCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 40}px`
        secondCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 40}px`
        thirdCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 100}px`

        if(childCount == 5){
            fourthCard.setAttribute('class','card fourth-card');
            fourthCard.style.marginTop = `${titleHeight + 100}px`
        }
    }
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2{
  font-weight:100;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

img{
  height: 60px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.one-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.two-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.more-item-container{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.header-container{
  padding: 2rem 6rem 0 0;
}

.header-container > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.more-header-container{
  padding: 2rem 6rem 0 0;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.more-header-container > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card{
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 1.5px 0  var(--c, #e0b9da);
  mask: linear-gradient(var(--p, 0deg), #0000 45%, #000 55%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card::after {
  --c: #b6dae7;
  --p: 180deg;
}


.card img{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card h3{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.card p{
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.one-item-first-card{
  grid-column: 2;
}

.two-item-first-card{
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.two-item-second-card{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.more-first-card{
  margin-bottom: calc(45%) ;
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.more-second-card{
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.third-card{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.fourth-card{
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}


button {
  position: absolute;
  top:5rem;
  right:5rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="header-container">
        <p>Solutions</p>
        <h2 id="cardTitle">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, tenetur.
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-pills.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=1FDCEF23CA8F9B5C6E1327B9A6FD4DAF"
            alt="Product Information"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Product Information</h3>
          <p>Learn about safety, administration, efficacy and more</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image">
          <img
            src="/-/jssmedia/Eisai-Emea/Shared/Icons/icon-documents.svg?iar=0&amp;hash=13316F3944BF062DA0708F1A38BDFF3D"
            alt="Patient Information"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="card__text">
          <h3>Patient information material</h3>
          <p>Handouts, treatment guides, patient support material</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<button>Resize</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I absolutely want to avoid having to use a javascript method.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways in which you can implement it,

##### Using flexbox and set widths

so, we would want to set the width that we want the cards to take a maximum, and for the title, we would set flex-wrap, so when it has no space the line breaks. Eventually, the lines would break so much that it is not readable, but you can adjust the size when the screen gets smaller with media queries.

in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/GuyNachshon/6np7s3xt/4/), the cards and their container have a set width.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antonio:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  &__headers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
  
    &__tagline {
      font-family: antonio, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.5rem;
    }

    &__title {
      display: flex;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 24px;
      max-width: 80%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  }

  &__cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    &__card {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0 20px;
      background-color: #ef546d;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">Solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">Improve the benefits that health care can provide</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">Solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">Improve the benefits that health care can provide</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">Solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">Improve the benefits that health care can provide</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">Solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">Improve the benefits that health care can provide</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
      <div class="row__cards__card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### using flexbox and flex-flow - title goes up

we will take advantage of the flexibility of flexbox and will set our `row` and `row__cards` `flex-flow` to `row wrap` (combination of `flex-wrap` and `flex-direction`). this results in the title going above the cards when it runs out of space and in the cards wrapping to a new line when they run out of space. you can take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/GuyNachshon/hktubLy4/33/)

```css
$title-max-width: 38%;  // You can change it to whatever you`d like
$card-size: 200px; 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  &__headers {
    max-width: $title-max-width;
  }
  
  &__cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 20px;
    
    &__card {
      background-color: white;
      height: $card-size;
      width: $card-size;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">
        Improve the benefits that health care can provide
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">
        Improve the benefits that health care can provide
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">
        Improve the benefits that health care can provide
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row__headers">
      <div class="row__headers__tagline">solutions</div>
      <div class="row__headers__title">
        Improve the benefits that health care can provide
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row__cards">
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row__cards__card">
        <div class="row__cards__card__text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

let me know if it doesn't fit your needs!